# Saving Intervention Image In Owners Folder in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, intervention

I can change my code to save the uploaded image in the public dir but not when I want to their uploaded image in a folder as their company's name. For example of what works:

```
/public/company_img/<filename>.jpg
```

If the user's company name is Foo, I want this when they save save their uploaded image:

```
/public/company_img/foo/<filename>.jpg
```

This is in my controller:

```
$image = Input::file('company_logo');
$filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
$path = public_path('company_img/' . Auth::user()->company_name . '/' . $filename);

// I am saying to create the dir if it's not there.
File::exists($path) or File::makeDirectory($path); // this seems to be the issue

// saving the file
Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize('280', '200')->save($path);
```

Just looking at that you can easily see what it's doing. My logs shows nothing and the browser goes blank after I hit the update button. Any ideas

Comment: Does the user which is executing the PHP (ie the webserver) have the permissions necessary for creating files and folders in that location?

Comment: @Joe yes. Im only getting a blank browser. No logs, no error.

Comment: is `File::exists($path) or File::makeDirectory($path);` valid PHP syntax? I've never seen an IF statement written in that format.

Comment: could you post your complete controller function? blank pages could be simply caused because your controller doesn't echo or return anything

Comment: @shock_gone_wild See here: `http://laravel.io/bin/xKY8P`

Comment: strange, that you are getting a complete white page.... if you do a dd("test") at the beginning of your update function, then it is displayed ?

Comment: @shock_gone_wild Yes Im getting that function when I `dd('here');`

Comment: another reason for the blank screen could be, that your storage/logs directory is not writeable by your application. Have you checked your apache error_log ( additionally to laravel logs ).

Comment: @shock_gone_wild Im new to laravel so I have not looked at the apache error_log.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
File::exists($path) or File::makeDirectory($path);
```

This line does not make sense, as you check if a file exists and if not you want to attempt to create a folder ( in your $path variable you saved a path to a file not to a directory )

I would do something like that:

```
        // directory name relative to public_path()
    $dir = public_path("company_img/username"); // set your own directory name there

    $filename = "test.jpg"; // get your own filename here

    $path = $dir."/".$filename;

    // check if $folder is a directory
    if( ! \File::isDirectory($dir) ) {

        // Params:
        // $dir = name of new directory
        //
        // 493 = $mode of mkdir() function that is used file File::makeDirectory (493 is used by default in \File::makeDirectory
        //
        // true -> this says, that folders are created recursively here! Example:
        // you want to create a directory in company_img/username and the folder company_img does not
        // exist. This function will fail without setting the 3rd param to true
        // http://php.net/mkdir  is used by this function

        \File::makeDirectory($dir, 493, true);
    }


    // now save your image to your $path
```

But i really can't say your behaviour has something to do with that... Without error messages, we can only guess.

Comment: You are the boss I tell you! I even got the correct if statement but still had write permission issues etc! One last thing, how do I reference the image path for a user and store in a db?